# Объект очень медленно падает

Tags: c#, unity3d

Импортирую объект в Unity3d, привязываю BoxCollider и RigidBody. Падает очень медленно, изменял параметры rigidbody - безуспешно. Видимо, этот объект слишком большой. Что мне с ним сделать? Уменьшить, или какой-то параметр изменить? Если уменьшить, то как?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В настройках измените настройки физики.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/class-PhysicsManager.html

Comment: Спасибо, изменил гравитацию.